# How to update current date every time in popup?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a table with two columns (created by and updated by)'with EO,VO. I have inserted the current date and time by using expression 'adf.currentDateTime' in view object. Similarly I want to capture the updated date and time while making changes in data everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture both created and modified moment using builtin feature "history column".

Comment: Another good option is to override entity's doDML method and set needed date on INSERT and UPDATE.

Comment: Means you saying that in EO level, Select that particular attribute  and track change history in build feature to modified on or created date .am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to set the default value of your View Object date attribute to "adf.currentDateTime" for it to be defaulted to the current time when the View object is triggered.

To *"capture the updated date and time while making changes in data everytime"* In your Jsf just put the inputDate attributes **immediate="true"** and **autoSubmit="true"** so when the user change the date in the UI it will update the value in the View Object in real time.

```
<af:inputDate value="#{row.bindings.Date.inputValue}" autoSubmit="true" immediate="true" id="id1">
 <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.CreationDate.validator}"/>
 <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{bindings.VO.hints.Date.format}"/>
</af:inputDate>
```